# Laravel fills attributes in model in migration even though they are not fillable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two entities:

1. Person, which has workspace_id column
2. PersonRevision, which does not have workspace_id column

In a migration I have this:

```
$persons = Person::all();

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $revision = new PersonRevision;
    $revision->fill($person->getAttributes());
    $revision->save();
}
```

PersonRevision does not have `workspace_id` in `fillable` property. But for some reason I got an error: `column "workspace_id" of relation "person_revisions" does not exist`.

Besides, if I run the migration second time (by just typing `php artisan migrate` second time) it works fine.

What could be the reason? I know I can manually list attributes which need to be filled, or use `array_except` but this is inconvenient and does not answer why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check what the actual sql statement is that's executed? To me it seems like you have a database which does not contain `workspace_id` yet, but your model does expect it to be there. Even when not filling the `workspace_id` the query generated from your eloquent model will probably try to update it with the value `null`, which it can't do if it's not there.

Because of issues like this it's best not to use eloquent models in database migrations, instead use raw sql.

Comment: Here is the the query: "insert into "person_revisions" ("id", "workspace_id",... ". preson_revisions does not have worskpace_id column and the attribute is not in fillable list on PersonRevision model.

Comment: So it seems that the `workspace_id` is inserted into the database. Could you check what value is used for it? If my guess is correct it's `null`.

Comment: No, it's "1", which is workspace_id value of Person. All Persons have the same workspace_id which is 1

Comment: Ah in that case my guess was wrong. Looking at the [laravel code for the fill method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L325), the `fillable` property should be respected indeed. You could check if the `"1"` value of `workspace_id` is set some other way. Maybe a default value? Maybe it's there when you create the `PersonRevision`? Try dumping the data of $revision` before calling the `fill` to see if it already has values. Or do you have any event handlers or other hooks which modify the data?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel SeedCommand handle() function runs with Model::ungarded() which forces all props to be fillable. When unguarded is true it auto fills regardless of fillable array.

```
public function isFillable($key)
{
    if (static::$unguarded) {
        return true;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Simply add this atop your seeder file Model::reguard();